# SQL , self join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a set of data

```
name
AASADF2
AASADF3
ADSFFD2
ADSFFD3
AAWFWEF
SFASFSF
ADAQWEW
ASDAWFA
FSDGFRG
AFWEFR2
AFWEFR3
```

I wanted to retrieve data with name ending 2 or 3 also first 6 character should match

```
i.e
AASADF2
AASADF3
ADSFFD2
ADSFFD3
AFWEFR2
AFWEFR3
```

I was able to display the data vertically using self join

```
AASADF2     AASADF3
ADSFFD2     ADSFFD3
AFWEFR2     AFWEFR3
```

But I wanted that in horizontal format

```
AASADF2
AASADF3
ADSFFD2
ADSFFD3
AFWEFR2
AFWEFR3
```

Do we need to create temp table for this to acheive this format
Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post your current query.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want :

```
select t.*
from table t
where right(nm, 1) in ('2', '3') and
      exists (select 1 from table t1 where left(t1.nm, 6) = left(t.nm, 6))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But it did not work , Because the presence of left(t.nm, 6)), The 't' says invalid object, since its scope is within the sub query

Comment: @PEL1. . . You need to replace `table` with your actual table name for both `outer` & `subquery`.

Comment: I did that, I just kept a 't' for your understanding

Comment: if you add a row 'ZZZZZZ3' you'll see that the code doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT distinct t1.field FROM TABLE t1 JOIN TABLE t2 
                   ON t1.field != t2.field 
                      AND RIGHT(t1.field,1 ) IN ('2', '3')
                      AND LEFT(t1.field, 6) = LEFT(t2.field,6);
```

--*********************************************

here is a full example for you

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
  field nvarchar(10)
)

insert @table (field) values ('AASADF2'),
                        ('AASADF3'),
                        ('ADSFFD2'),
                        ('ADSFFD3'),
                        ('AAWFWEF'),
                        ('SFASFSF'),
                        ('ADAQWEW'),
                        ('ASDAWFA'),
                        ('FSDGFRG'),
                        ('AFWEFR2'),
                        ('AFWEFR3');



SELECT distinct t1.field FROM @table t1 JOIN @table t2 
                   ON t1.field != t2.field 
                      AND RIGHT(t1.field,1 ) IN ('2', '3')
                      AND LEFT(t1.field, 6) = LEFT(t2.field,6)
```

output

```
field
----------
AASADF2
AASADF3
ADSFFD2
ADSFFD3
AFWEFR2
AFWEFR3

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But its is not showing the data as expected

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
I was able to retrieve partial results, If we check count > 1 which will show the results which I am looking for , I used the below query

;with cte as (select t1.name from t_name t1

where substring(t1.name, 8, 1) in ( select substring(t2.name, 8, 1) from t_name t2 where substring(t2.name, 8, 1)='2' or substring(t2.name, 8, 1)='3' ) )

B2018BT2 1 B2018BU2 1 B2018BV2 1 B2018BW2 1 B2018BX2 1 B2018BY2 1 B2018BZ2 1 B2020AA2 2 B2020AA3 2 B2020AB2 2 B2020AB3 2 B2020AC2 2 B2020AC3 2

Can someone suggest how to do a filer on count>1?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what results you do want.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by left(t.field, 6)) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1 and field like '%[23]';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve partial results,
If  we check count > 1 which will show the results which I am looking for , I used the below query

;with cte as
(select  t1.name   from t_name  t1

where   substring(t1.name, 8, 1) in
 (
 select substring(t2.name, 8, 1) from t_name t2
 where 
  substring(t2.name, 8, 1)='2' 
 or substring(t2.name, 8, 1)='3'
  )
  )

B2018BT2    1
B2018BU2    1
B2018BV2    1
B2018BW2    1
B2018BX2    1
B2018BY2    1
B2018BZ2    1
B2020AA2    2
B2020AA3    2
B2020AB2    2
B2020AB3    2
B2020AC2    2
B2020AC3    2

Can someone suggest how to do a filer on count>1?